# Туша и дичь (различия и сходства)

Tags: лексика

Проведите, пожалуйста, границу между понятиями "туша" и "дичь".

Дичью может быть мясо любого убитого животного, а не только птицы? Можно ли назвать тушей неразделанное мясо?

Answer (score 1):

*Туша* ("тушка" для птицы и мелких животных) - убитое животное в **начальной стадии разделки** (целое или с некоторыми отделёнными или извлечёнными частями), напр. для использования в пищу. Животное может быть как из домашнего скота, так и диким (кабан, утка).

*Дичь* - **убитое на охоте с целью употребления в пищу** дикое животное, чаще всего птица. Наименование сохраняется и для приготовленного блюда, независимо от его разделения на порции и т. п.

Comment: А можно ли тушью называть готовое блюдо, филе, отбивную  и т. д.? И дичью.

Comment: Про тушу так сказать нельзя, про дичь - можно. В таких случаях говорят или пишут (напр. об официальном приёме): на второе блюдо _подали дичь_. Туша может быть как сырой (обычно без шкуры и потрошёная), так и зажаренной на вертеле _целиком_ (сохраняющей форму животного), иначе это может быть напр. "полтуши".

Comment: Дичь - это именно собственноручно убитый зверь? Или он может быть куплен специально? А если их разводят на специальной фабрике, но их не держат обыкновенные люди в народе, и обычно они обитают в лесу?

Comment: Не обязательно собственноручно (можно купить у охотника), но обязательно дикое (не разводимое на ферме) животное (заяц, кабан) или птица (чаще именно птица - глухарь, дикая утка). Дичью обобщённо называют и _объект охоты_: охотник _выслеживает дичь_ (ещё не зная, какая попадётся).

Comment: А где вы находите эту информацию?

Comment: В собственной памяти :) По поводу дичи: есть известнейший эпизод в фильме Бриллиантовая рука (сцена в ресторане), где "подают дичь". Часто цитируют реплику оттуда (сигнал официанту принести дичь в нужный момент): "Федя, дичь!!!" Про тушу: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D1%82%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8

Answer (score 0):

В традиции Русского языка, Дичью может быть и олень в качестве приготовленого блюда добытый на охоте! В "гастрономическом" понятии дичь это чаще всего птица причем не домашняя, либо как минимум равная домашней( утка или гусь напр., возможны любые как блюдо но только охотничий трофей называют ДИЧЬю), фазан или вяхирь всегда считались дичью.То же относится и к в качестве "охотничего трофея" полученной в пищу добыче, неявляющаяся домашним животным.Без учета того что олень у народов севера это не то что олень для народов умеренной климатической части планеты. Хотя возможен еще "иносказательно-идиомное" высказывание напр., :- Что за ДИЧЬ вы тут понаписали?! ; Это еще что за ДИЧЬ?; ДИЧЬ какая-то!!; и т.п.